# XAMPP Cannot load stack definitions error

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp, localhost

I've been getting this error for the past two days. I have so much work on here. I need to know if there's a way to access them to fix this issue or something. The error says: cannot load stack definitions. It was working fine yesterday afternoon then when I went back to do more work at night, it just showed this and I haven't been able to fix it.

[image: This is the error I get when I open XAMPP on my MacBook Pro]

Comment: are you using a vm?

Comment: no im not. Just straight from my MacBook. The strange thing is that its been working this entire time up until literally just last night. I have so much work on there. Is there any way to access those php, css, html, js, etc. files?

Comment: This error message can come from not enough free space   and of course you can access all files and restore it on a VM or where you like they are only simple files , which can v es copied anywhere for MySQL you need somewhat more work to restore but not much

Comment: Not enough free space on my MacBook? And also, how can I access my files? If I can just get those files, I'll be fine